# How can I call distinct on entities in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables where users save data for cities. I want to count the total number of cities in both tables using a Distinct on the join query.

```
Table 1       Table 2

ID City       ID City
--------      ----------
1  CHD        1  PUT
2  PUT        2  CHD
3  LUD        3  MALK
4  CHD        4  PUT
5  PUT        5  APC
```

I want to join both tables and get the total count of Cities, but I want to make sure that cites will not be repeated in the count. That is, if CHD exists in table 1 and Table 2 then only count it once.

I don't want to count cities repeatedly. I want to be able to filter my results and get the total count.

I have written this code for Table 1 but I want the same result with a joined query.

```
public int Locations()
{
    int Locations = 0;           

    using (var db = new Entities())
        Locations = db.Table1.Select(o => o.City).Distinct().Count();          

    int Locations = 0;           

    using (var db = new Entities())
        Locations = db.Table2.Select(o => o.City).Distinct().Count();

    return Locations;
}
```

How can I do this with 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it might be what you're looking for.

```
public int Locations()
{         
     using (var db = new Entities()) 
     {
          return (db.Table1.Select(x => x.City).Union(db.Table2.Select(y => y.City)))
                 .Distinct().Count()
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank You #Dillon its really help full.

Answer (score 0):

Do a LINQ `Union`, which will automatically only take uniques from each component list:

```
var locations = table1Locations.Union(table2Locations);
```

Bear in mind that this will only work because you're selecting just the `City` from each table. That means you're effectively combining two `IEnumerable<string>`s. If you were to try to combine the objects directly it would fail, because you'd essentially have an `IEnumerable<Table1Entity>` and `IEnumerable<Table2Entity>`, which cannot be unioned.